# RequiredFieldValidator　の動的エラー表示について

Tags: asp.net

asp.net について質問です。

入力値を検証するため、RequiredFieldValidatorプロパティを利用したのですが
RangeValidatorとは違って動的にエラー検証がされませんでした。
サーバーにポストバックされて初めてRequiredFieldValidatorが動的に検証できるようになったのですが、それぞれのプロパティでそのような制御があるのでしょうか。

```
  年齢
    <asp:TextBox ID="Age" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="必須項目です"
        ControlToValidate="Age"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RangeValidator Id="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="年齢は0-15の範囲"
        ControlToValidate="Age" InitialValue="テキストを入力"
        Maximumvalue="15" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer">
    </asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

バリデーターがクライアント側で動作するかどうかは[BaseValidator.EnableClientScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx)プロパティで設定できます。
ただし`RequiredFieldValidator`のこのプロパティの既定値は`true`です。質問文のコードをこちらで動作させても検証は実行されていますので、他のスクリプトエラー等で動作が停止したり、予期しないポストバックが行われていないかを確認したほうが良いと思われます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
回答者さまのとおり、スクリプトエラーで動作が停止しておりました。。。
大変お騒がせしました。